# Change case owner using workflow rules doesn't trigger the email notification

Tags: community, workflow, case, email-alert, web2case

We have a lightning community with a "Create a case form". Using a workflow rule we assign the case to a queue (by default it is assigned to the community user) and we expect that the users of that queue are notified, but this is not happening.

- We also tried with the process builder but doesn't work as well (apparently a known issue)
- The Notify Assignee checkbox on the workflow is checked
- The Send Email to Members checkbox on the queue is checked
- We tried with the "All email" level access in the deliverability section but nothing changed.
- Manually changing the owner from the user to the queue and checking the Send notification email checkbox works.

Is this a known issue or are we missing something that is preventing us to notify the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this by using a process builder that starts on case creation. It switches the case owner to the queue and than uses an email alert with the queue as recipient.

This shouldn't be needed but is a necessary workaround to make it work within a lightning community.

Comment: this works for me. Thanks! It was very frustrating that case assignment rule notification is not working for me and also workflow notify assignee in WFR is not working either.